# How to stash current changes and apply it to a new branch

Tags: git, git-stash

I'm currently working on a project git is used as the version control. I'm currently in the 0.27.0.i1 branch. And I have some changes which have not still committed to the master branch. These changes has to be committed to the new 0.27.0.i2 branch which originated from the 0.27.0.i1.

How can I stash changes from the 0.27.0.i1 and apply the stashed changes on the 0.27.0.i2 branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do

```
git stash
git checkout 0.27.0.i2
git stash pop
git commit -a
```

Comment: This might not even be necessary. If the branches are similar enough, a simple `git checkout 0.27.0.i2` will carry over your uncommitted changes, and you can just commit after that.

Comment: True, I was about to try it right now because I wasn't sure:)

Answer (score 1):

When you haven't changes in the target branch you can simply checkout the new branch. Then all your changes will be in the new branch.

When you have changes in the new branch you can't checkout the other branch but in your case its not a problem i think.